# How can I use protobuf::parse_from_bytes for a Rust struct?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I have defined a `ProcessState` structure:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Default)]
pub struct ProcessState {
    pub file_sample: FileSample,
    pub estimate: Estimate,
    pub estimate_cache: HashMap<String, Estimate>,
    pub total_count: u64,
    pub systems: HashMap<String, SystemState>,
    pub aggregate_clock: u64,
    pub aggregate_mean: f64,
    pub file_samples: VecDeque<FileSample>,
}
```

How do I make use of the [`parse_from_bytes`](https://docs.rs/protobuf/*/protobuf/fn.parse_from_bytes.html) function on this? Do I need to define a proto message for my structure in order to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand how this works, you can't implement this yourself: the API is designed to generate Rust code from a `.proto` file.

The [doc](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/#invoke-protoc-programmatically-with-protoc-rust-crate-recommended) says that the recommended way is to use [protoc-rust](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/tree/master/protoc-rust) to generate the code.

As for what to write in the `.proto` file, the [doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) is here.

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur. This was what I was thinking as well. But was just to able to see anything around the parse_from_bytes method documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: https://github.com/jgarzik/rust-protobuf-example/tree/master

You don't need to define `parse_from_bytes` yourself.